# listener for $route.params to be defined in run()

Tags: angularjs

I need to call a service in the `run()`-section of an angular app.

In this service I need to access `$route.current.params`, which is not defined when calling it from the `run()` part.

Is it possible to attach an event listener in the `run()` part of the application which listens for `$route.current.params` to be defined? Maybe there is a better place to call my service function, but I need it to be called when the application starts.

My solution is to use `$timeout` but I hoped that there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Which router do you use ? ngRouter or Ui-Router ?

Answer (score 1):

On angular's documentation they say:

> $routeChangeStart
>
> Broadcasted before a route change. At this point the
>   route services starts resolving all of the dependencies needed for the
>   route change to occur. Typically this involves fetching the view
>   template as well as any dependencies defined in resolve route
>   property. Once all of the dependencies are resolved
>   $routeChangeSuccess is fired.
>
> The route change (and the $location change that triggered it) can be
>   prevented by calling preventDefault method of the event. See
>   $rootScope.Scope for more details about event object.

Doc link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

You can do it like that:

```
 run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
      // check anything you want
    });
  });
```

Update: (based on the first comment below)

You can do it like that:

```
 run(function($route) {
    // do whatever you need with $route.currrent.params
  });
```

Comment: That would be an option, but I only want to do the initialization at the beginning. Not on every routeChange.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `EventListener`

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('page loading completed');
});
```

Comment: What are the advantages compared to using a $timeout with a delay of 0?

Comment: I don't think with a `$timeout` you're 100% certain the document is loaded.

Comment: As far as I know the function given to `$timeout` will executed after the current digest, so I can be sure `$route` is defined